# What minimal SMTP client will allow me to relay cron output to an external email address?

Tags: ubuntu, email, unix, cron

I would like to have cron output sent to an external email address, via a minimal SMTP client that sends via Gmail. I think I need this client to support TLS and /etc/aliases, and I would like configuration to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Similar questions on [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/): [Lightweight outgoing SMTP server](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/lightweight-outgoing-smtp-server), [Simplest way of forwarding all mail from server?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/simplest-way-of-forwarding-all-mail-from-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ssmtp seems to be abandoned.  Generally people are using [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) as an equivalent replacement. Here's a [decent howto](http://www.brintech.net/msmtp-easy-sendmail-replacement-for-mdadm-e-mails/) on how to use msmtp as your system mail transfer agent.

msmtp supports all the standard authentication and encryption protocols such as TLS.

Comment: msmtp does not seem to support aliases, so I can't see how to get root's email from cron to the outside world.

Comment: aliases are for mail coming in to your system, not going out.  For outgoing mail, you rewrite the header and envelope header to control who the mail appears to be from.  msmtp can do that.

Comment: msmtp now support aliases.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really minimal, but it's there in virtually all Ubuntu repositories -- postfix.

I typically configure postfix to relay all my email to gmail, and I made a script to automate configuring postfix on new Ubuntu installations. [Feel free to check this out to get the script](https://gist.github.com/3952294).

Answer (score 0):

On my fedora and centos box I run ssmtp which allows me to forward my cron and daily mail to my gmail account.

Works as well as expected and is easy to setup.